# How to remove double quotes in each cell of Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code that would remove double quotes in each cell of Excel

```
Sub NoNull()
Dim c As Range
 For Each c In Selection
   If c.Value = " " Then c.ClearContents
 Next c
End Sub
```

the current cell that I have contains a string enclosed with double quotes when pasted in an editor. For example, in Excel it appears as

```
text text2
```

and when viewed from the editor, it appears as

```
line 1: "text
line 2: text2"
```

I would like to remove the double quote so that when opened in csv, it would treat the value as one case - not multiple cases. How do I modify the code above?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the code you show does not delete double quotes, it makes cells that contain a single space into empty cells.  The double quotes are not stored in the spreadsheet, but they are added when the sheet is saved as a CSV.  Are the two values, text  and text2 in separate cells?  If so, then they will be saved as separate string values in the CSV.  To merge consecutive cell values into a single string in the CSV will take some different handling.

Comment: Use the replace function and look for chr(34) which is the double quote  Replace(c.value,chr(34),"")

Comment: @Hrothgar - No, they are just in one cell. But if I copied the the text in the text editor it would display as multiple lines. I want it as to be one line only since when I import it in SPSS it would be treated as separate case.

Comment: @Sorceri; do you mean this code?

Sub NoNull()
Dim c As Range
 For Each c In Selection
    Replace(c.Value,chr(34),"")
 Next c
End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comment you want to remove the line feeds
so remove them via replace function.  The line feed could be any one of chr(10) or vbCrLf or vbCr.  An example is below.

```
For Each c In Selection
   c.Value = Replace(c.Value, Chr(10), " ")
 Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say C1 is the cell that has the bad data. In a new cell, type =CLEAN(C1). Then a clean version of the C1 cell with no double qoutes will appear. Then while your new cleaned cell is highlighted, double click the little square in the bottom right to autofill the same formula for all of the cells under the dirty one. Then copy your new clean column of data, and paste it over the old one.